# Gradient under integration in infinite domain

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

Consider the probability space $\left(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathcal{F}, \mu \right)$, where the probability measure $\mu$ has bounded density $\rho$, and consider
\begin{equation}
   f(s)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \|s-x\|_2 \mu(dx),
\end{equation}
where $s, x \in \mathbb{R}^3$. I want to compute gradient of $f(s)$ with respect to $s$. I understand I have to use the dominated convergence theorem. My approach is for $h \in \mathbb{R}^3$,
\begin{equation}
\frac{f\left(s_1+e_1h,s_2,s_3\right) }{|h|}= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{\left(s_1+e_1h-x_1\right)^2+\left(s_2-x_2\right)^2+\left(s_3-x_3\right)^2}-\sqrt{\left(s_1-x_1\right)^2+\left(s_2-x_2\right)^2+\left(s_3-x_3\right)^2}}{|h|}\rho \left(x_1,x_2,x_3\right)dx_1dx_2dx_3.
\end{equation}

But to apply DCT at first I have to show $\Bigg \vert \frac{\partial}{\partial s_i}\|s-x\|_2 \Bigg \vert \leq g\left(x\right)$, where $g\left(x\right) \in L^1\left(\mathbb{R}^3\right)$. I am struggling with this.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Fix $s\in \mathbb R^n$, $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$ and let $g(s,x) := \| s-x \|_2$. For $h\in \mathbb R$, \begin{align*}
\frac{f(s+he_i)-f(s)} h &= \int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{g(s+he_i,x)-g(s,x)} h \, \mu (dx).
\end{align*} Since you only care about computing the gradient of $f$ pointwise, it is enough to show that $$ \tag{$\ast$}\bigg \vert  \frac{g(s+he_i,x)-g(s,x)} h\bigg \vert \leqslant \varphi_s(x) $$ where $\varphi$ is independent of $h$ (but may depend on $s$) and $\varphi_s \in L^1(d\mu)$.

Then, we have that\begin{align*}
\bigg \vert\frac{g(s+he_i,x)-g(s,x)} h\bigg \vert & \leqslant \sup_{\tilde s\in \mathbb R^n} \vert \partial_{s_i}g(\tilde s,x) \vert 
\end{align*} and $$\vert \partial_{s_i}g(\tilde s,x) \vert =\bigg \vert \frac{\tilde s_i-x_i}{\| \tilde s-x\|_2} \bigg \vert \leqslant 1. $$ Since $\mu$ is a probability measure, constant functions are in $L^1(d\mu)$, so ($\ast$) holds with $\varphi_s(x) = 1$.

Hence, by the dominated convergence theorem, $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial s_i}(s) = \int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{\partial g} {\partial s_i} (s,x) \, \mu (dx) $$ for each $i=1,\dots,n$.

Comment: Thank you @JackT. I have a few confusion. I will appreciate it if you kindly explain.

Comment: What is the logic behind the following inequality, $$\Bigg \vert \frac{g\left(s+he_i,x\right)-g\left(s,x\right)}{h} \Bigg \vert \leq \underset{\tilde{s} \in \mathbb{R}^n}{\sup} |\partial_{s_i}g\left( \tilde{s},x\right)|$$.

Comment: I also have another question. If I want to compute the gradient of $f$ uniformly, then how can I do that? I mean if I want to compute $\nabla_{s} f\left(s\right)$, then how can I do that? Thank you again.